# Holding two UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to make my UIView swipeable by X-axis and by Y-axis separately. For example if user swipes view vertically it triggers one action and if user swipes view horizontally it triggers another action. I don't know how to implement this correctly so I'm thinking of attaching two `UIPanGestureRecognizer`s to my view. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and use its `translation(in: UIView?)` and `velocity(in: UIView?)` functions to determine which direction the user is swiping.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use two Gesture use only single UIPanGestureRecognizer and call this method with your panGesture:

```
 -(void)moveVerticallyAndHorizentally:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

    CGPoint velocity = [gesture velocityInView:self.view]; // you can use your own view

    if (fabs(velocity.y) > fabs(velocity.x)) {

       // vertical motion
    }
   else if (fabs(velocity.x) > fabs(velocity.y)){

    // Horizental motion
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you.